# Does TransactWriteItem reduce consumed write unit?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having some optimization problems with DynamoDB. I believe I don't need to show any code here, so I just ask my question,

My items have a "list" attribute.
What I need to do is, iterate this table, add new values to the list attribute of every item. Since every update operation is different from each other, this operation requires lots of write units.
To reduce this, I group items by 25, and update them with TransactionWriteItem. I couldn't compare values exactly but I felt that it had no effect.

I also have another question, if my data is 100 byte (smaller than 4KB), would it make any difference if I zip it? I mean, is there a difference between 100 byte and 10 byte in terms of consumed write units?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, I just learned that UpdateItem works terrible. It uses the whole Item size in calculation of WCU, therefore It doesn't matter if I append a tiny data to an attribute or rewrite whole item. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The transactions API is not meant to speed things up, or consume less capacity: it is designed to allow atomic operations across multiple items (this means that either all updates succeed, or all fail, as a unit).

Compare this with doing 25 updates yourself, or using the BatchWriteItem API -- in these cases, some updates could fail while other succeed. Or they may all succeed but other reads may happen while you're update your items causing inconsistent views on your data.

So, to better understand consumed write capacity, it goes like this: any item being updated (this includes creating new, deleting existing, or updating existing) will consume at least 1 capacity unit. There is no way for an item update to consume fractional capacity units (ie. if your updates are really tiny). But it is possible for a single item update to consume more than 1 WCU, if the item is larger than 1KB.

So it does pay off to compress your items, if they are large(er) than 1KB.

In fact, even if smaller than 1KB it pays off to strive for small items because unlike writes which always consume at least 1KB, when querying or scanning, the consumed capacity is calculated for the aggregate sum of the returned results of the query or scan. For example, if your query retrieves 10 items and each item is 200B you will only get charged 1 RCU; but if the same query returns 10 items and each item is 1KB then you'd consume 3RCU (10KB / 4KB = 2.5, rounded up is 3)

Comment: Thanks, can I also ask what is the best practise for updating an item? For my case,
I'm appending a very tiny object to a list, but writing capacity is calculated based on whole item size. What should I do if I want to append 50byte to a 300kb item? Do I have to pay writing capacity of 300 kb?